# Can I Use WinAppDeployCmd install, update on pc itself

Tags: uwp, windows-10

I have my .appx file for installation in folder. I can install it by double clicking the file.

But i am looking for a way to install it using WinAppDeployCmd for installation and also for update process.

```
WinAppDeployCmd install -file "C:\release\file.appx" -ip 192.168.0.1
```

192.168.0.1 - is the ip of the pc itself.

I am getting error :
0x80131500 - The network event being waited on triggered an error.
0x8007274D - The network event being waited on triggered an error.

I am using windows 10.

Am i missing anything?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Can I Use WinAppDeployCmd install, update on pc itself

The simple answer is yes.

> I am getting error : 0x80131500 - The network event being waited on triggered an error.

If you want to install the package to your local machine by `WinAppDeployCmd`, you need to [Enable your device for development](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development) and [enable device discovery](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development#additional-developer-mode-features) firstly. The reason for getting this error should be you didn't enable device discovery. Please enable it in `Settings->Update & security->For Developers`:

[image]

After then this error will go but you may get  the following error and please following the Device Discovery section of [above document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/uwp/get-started/enable-your-device-for-development#additional-developer-mode-features) to get the Pin.

> Please retry the command with the "-pin" option and a valid pin as shown in the device settings.

And then you can install the app with command like:

`WinAppDeployCmd install -file "Downloads\MyApp.appx" -ip 192.168.0.1 -pin A1B2C3`

Comment: This worked for me but I needed to use `-guid` instead of `-ip` for deploying to my local machine. For remote machines, `-ip` worked fine. By the way, you can find the guid using `WinAppDeployCmd devices`.