# Run appx file in current Windows 10 device using the PowerShell cmdlets

Tags: windows, powershell, uwp, powershell-cmdlet

I have an appx file which was generated elsewhere and I would like to test it in my Windows 10 machine.

The appx file is already available to me and I can deploy it to other devices using the `WinAppDeployCmd`, which works for the XBox One. This works perfectly with the following command:

```
WinAppDeployCmd install -file "!MY_FILE!" -ip "!DEVICE_IP!" -pin "!DEVICE_PIN!"
```

My question is, is there a similar command to simply run my `.appx` in the windows machine where it currently is? Is there perhaps even a way to use the `WinAppDeployCmd` to install it in the current machine?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know about cmd, but in PowerShell you can use

```
Add-AppxPackage -Path C:\Users\User\MyApp.appx
```

If the package is unsigned, you will need to enable developer mode in Windows 10 before it can be installed.

1. Open Settings.
2. Click on Update & security
3. Click on For developers.
4. Under “Use developer features”, enable Developer mode.

More information on Add-AppxPackage: https://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/hh856048.aspx

**Update:** Regarding using `WinAppDeployCmd` for this see: [Can I Use WinAppDeployCmd install, update on pc itself](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45894261/can-i-use-winappdeploycmd-install-update-on-pc-itself)

Comment: Run `Install-Module -Name PackageManagement -RequiredVersion 1.1.7.0` to install the package manager.