# Install W10 Store apps from CLI

Tags: python, windows, powershell, cmd, store

I'm making a little python script that automatically downloads and install certain apps from the store to not to forget some of them in case i format my pc.

Is there a way to install those app from cmd/powershell so i can call this in python?

Comment: There's [Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/uwp/api/Windows.Management.Deployment.PackageManager), and it looks like you can use [WinAppDeployCmd locally](https://stackoverflow.com/q/45894261/243245) if you change a setting too, but it doesn't look like either can download from the store.